# Access another activity's UI element using view binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

I Have an activity having a button "Next" under that I have NavHostController for fragments. I am using that button to navigate though fragments using NavComponemts grapgh. I've set on click lister on button in activity that will call a function in fragment that will navigate to next fragment. But When I am on last fragment I want to hide that button. That the problem.

We can access another activity's UI element simply using kotlin synthetic. When migrating to jetpack view binding I realised that the `binding` is private to that particular activity , there is no way to do this.
There is no documentation about this

Comment: it's probably a horrible idea to be doing it, either way. you're asking for bugs and nullpointers, so you probably shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I Have an activity having a button "Next" under that I have NavHostController for fragments. I am using that button to navigate though fragments using NavComponemts grapgh. I've set on click lister on button in activity that will call a function in fragment that will navigate to next fragment. But When I am on last fragment I want to hide that button. That the problem

Comment: all of that is info that people need to give you answers, so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70095027/edit) your question to include all this info, and make sure that you include as much detail as possible when asking a question in future, i'm sure you'll find an answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But When I am on last fragment I want to hide that button. That the
> problem.

You can achieve this by adding a function in parent activity (activity having "Next" button) and call it when your last fragment is displayed.

In activity :

```
fun hideNextBtn() {
    binding.btnNext.isVisible = false
}
```

In last fragment :

```
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).hideNextBtn()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to access or do any change on any UI element from anywhere other than the Activity or Fragment it is part of. It might lead to. bugs.

Still if you want you can make the DataBinding object you get when calling DataBinding.setContentView() public or provide a getter method to access the same.

Comment: I want to change textview of another activity according to what user entered in 1st activity's textbox

Comment: @notBot either use a LocalBroadcast for sending this data or launch the new activity when user selects something & send the said data through bundle

Comment: `Use LocalBroadcast receiver for that.` that's a bad idea, there's no guarantee that the second activity will still be alive - only one activity is active at a time, for a reason. don't hack this, just use intents or a single activity with fragments. there are _proper_ ways of passing data around

Comment: @a_local_nobody you are right

Comment: @TaranmeetSingh There is another problem. I Have an activity having a button "Next" under that I have NavHostController for fragments. I am using that button to navigate though fragments using NavComponemts grapgh. I've set on click lister on button in activity that will call a function in fragment that will navigate to next fragment. But When I am on last fragment I want to hide that button. That the problem